# Module installation script isn't executing

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions

I tried to many ways to do this, but isn't executing.

app/code/local/Devra/Address/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Devra_Address>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Devra_Address>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <address>
                <class>Devra_Address_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>address_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </address>
            <address_mysql4>
                <class>Devra_Address_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <address>
                        <table>address</table>
                    </address>
                </entities>
            </address_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <address_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Devra_Address</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </address_setup>
            <address_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </address_write>
            <address_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </address_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <address>
                <class>Devra_Address_Block</class>
            </address>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <address>
                <class>Devra_Address_Helper</class>
            </address>
        </helpers>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <street_new>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                </street_new>
                <street_number>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                </street_number>
                <rut>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                </rut>
                <dpto_off>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                </dpto_off>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
            <customer_address>
                <street_new>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </street_new>
                <street_number>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </street_number>
                <rut>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </rut>
                <dpto_off>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </dpto_off>
            </customer_address>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Devra/Address/sql/address_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = $this;

$entityTypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer_address');
$attributeSetId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

//this is for creating a new attribute for customer address entity
$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'street_new', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Calle',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'backend' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'default' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'unique' => false
));

$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'rut', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'RUT',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'backend' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'default' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'unique' => false
));

$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'street_number', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Numeración',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'backend' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'default' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'unique' => false
));
$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'dpto_off', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Depto/Oficina',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'backend' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'default' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'unique' => false
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer_address', 'street_new')
->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
->setData("is_system", 0)
->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
->setData("is_visible", 1)
->setData("sort_order", 100)
->save();
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer_address', 'street_number')
->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
->setData("is_system", 0)
->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
->setData("is_visible", 1)
->setData("sort_order", 100)
->save();
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer_address', 'dpto_off')
->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
->setData("is_system", 0)
->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
->setData("is_visible", 1)
->setData("sort_order", 100)
->save();
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer_address', 'rut')
->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
->setData("is_system", 0)
->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
->setData("is_visible", 1)
->setData("sort_order", 100)
->save();


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'street_new', '995'  //sort_order
);
$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'street_number', '996'  //sort_order
);
$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'dpto_off', '997'  //sort_order
);
$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'rut', '998'  //sort_order
);


/**
 * Adding Extra Column to sales_flat_quote_address
 * to store the delivery instruction field
 */
$sales_quote_address = $installer->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'street_new', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New Street field'
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'street_number', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INT,
            'comment' => 'New Street number field'
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'dpto_off', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New Dpto field'
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'rut', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New RUT field'
        ));

/**
 * Adding Extra Column to sales_flat_order_address
 * to store the delivery instruction field
 */
$sales_order_address = $installer->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'street_new', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New Street field'
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'street_number', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INT,
            'comment' => 'New Street number field'
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'dpto_off', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New Dpto field'
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'rut', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New RUT field'
        ));


$config = Mage::getModel('core/config');

//append delivery instruction to address templates in system configuration
$html = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/html');
$html .= '{{depend street_new}}<br/>Calle: {{var street_new}} {{/depend}}';
$html .= '{{depend street_number}}<br/>Numeración: {{var street_number}} {{/depend}}';
$html .= '{{depend dpto_off}}<br/>Dpto/Oficina: {{var dpto_off}} {{/depend}}';
$html .= '{{depend rut}}<br/>RUT: {{var rut}} {{/depend}}';

$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/html', $html);

$text = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/text');
$text .= '{{depend street_new}}<br/>Calle: {{var street_new}} {{/depend}}';
$text .= '{{depend street_number}}<br/>Numeración: {{var street_number}} {{/depend}}';
$text .= '{{depend dpto_off}}<br/>Dpto/Oficina: {{var dpto_off}} {{/depend}}';
$text .= '{{depend rut}}<br/>RUT: {{var rut}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/text', $text);

$oneline = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/oneline');
$oneline .= '{{depend street_new}}<br/>Calle: {{var street_new}} {{/depend}}';
$oneline .= '{{depend street_number}}<br/>Numeración: {{var street_number}} {{/depend}}';
$oneline .= '{{depend dpto_off}}<br/>Dpto/Oficina: {{var dpto_off}} {{/depend}}';
$oneline .= '{{depend rut}}<br/>RUT: {{var rut}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/oneline', $oneline);

$pdf = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/pdf');
$pdf .= '{{depend street_new}}<br/>Calle: {{var street_new}} {{/depend}}';
$pdf .= '{{depend street_number}}<br/>Numeración: {{var street_number}} {{/depend}}';
$pdf .= '{{depend dpto_off}}<br/>Dpto/Oficina: {{var dpto_off}} {{/depend}}';
$pdf .= '{{depend rut}}<br/>RUT: {{var rut}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/pdf', $pdf);

$js_template = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/js_template');
$js_template .= '{{depend street_new}}<br/>Calle: {{var street_new}} {{/depend}}';
$js_template .= '{{depend street_number}}<br/>Numeración: {{var street_number}} {{/depend}}';
$js_template .= '{{depend dpto_off}}<br/>Dpto/Oficina: {{var dpto_off}} {{/depend}}';
$js_template .= '{{depend rut}}<br/>RUT: {{var rut}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/js_template', $js_template);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Also, this is the result for `core_resources`:

```
select * from core_resource where code like '%address%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I also cleaned the cache, so i don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have a file for the module in `app/etc/modules`? Without it Magento won't pick up the module

Comment: What happens if you remove `<class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>` from config.xml and also increase the version then clear the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your module available in the backend "system > configuration > advanced". If it isn't available check your /etc/modules folder, you should have created and "Devra_Address.xml" file here.

Sometimes Magento fails to run the setup script (caching, errors, ...)
A very usefull tool in situations like these is [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun). n98-magerun  is a bunch of CLI commands to help you with Magento development and maintenance. It has a script to force run setup's so you can see if yours is available and if Magento is able to run your script.

You can simply install it in your shell folder:

```
cd shell
```

And execute

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun.phar
```

After that you can force the incremental setup of modules:

```
php n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:incremental
```

You should see that there is (minimum) 1 script to install, and if you hit Enter it should install. If you don't see your script, then there is something wrong with your config.xml file.